# Calling subclass method in android

Tags: java, android

I want to call a method, located inside a subclass, from the onCreate method of the main class.

I tried something like this, but as the main class is somehow static i cannot make a reference to the non static subclass.
I do not want to make the subclass static!

```
public class NetworkBroadcast extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Caster.castMac();
    }

    public class Caster extends Thread {
        public void castMac() {}
    }
}
```

Comment: are you  not going to instantiate before you call a member function? and how is the parent class static if it is not declared as static!! This will help you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 3):

`castMac` is an *instance* method of `Caster`, which means you need to create (or otherwise obtain) an instance of `Caster` in order to call it. Alternatively, you could change `castMac` to be a static method. It's hard to tell which is appropriate as it's currently a no-op. If you could provide more context we may be able to give more concrete advice.

(As a secondary point, it's very rarely a good idea to extend `Thread`. Instead, implement `Runnable` and pass that into the `Thread` constructor.)

Comment: Sorry it was me. The author doesn't deserve your answer. It is basic Java. That's his job. I did that because I think you shouldn't answer.

Comment: @haibison: That's a really sucky reason for a downvote, IMO. Obviously you get to use your downvotes however you like, but that sort of attitude certainly isn't going to encourage me to answer any of *your* questions in the future.

Comment: To be honest I don't do his job. Basic Java is what he needs to learn himself. I understand what you said. _I've been doing downvote all the questions like this one, and all of the answers. I'm sorry._

Answer (score 1):

either make the castMac() method static

```
public static voic castMac() {}
```

or create an instance of your Caster class before calling `castMac()`

```
Caster c = new Caster();
c.castMac();
```